# Hibernate mapping without column in main table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am using Hibernate and i have 2 entties:

WeddingEntity:

```
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "guests")
private int guests;

and etc
```

WeddingPlanningEntity:

```
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@JoinColumn(name = "wedding_id")
private WeddingEntity wedding;

and etc
```

Is there a way to add in WeddingEntity a new property with a list of WeddingPlannings?

I need this because i want to use the Hibernates criteria, is there any way? or i have to use HQL?

Comment: Use a OneToMany in WeddingEntity https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html

Answer (score 2):

You can have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wedding")
private List<WeddingPlanningEntity> plannings;
```

And in `WeddingPlanningEntity` class add `@ManyToOne` on `wedding`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "wedding_id")
private WeddingEntity wedding;
```

PS. No need to call your entities `SomethingEntity`, as `Something` is just fine. You have already annotated it with `@Entity`.